# Setting state in a subcomponent of react-table closes component resetting all states with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I've been using react-table heavily throughout my React app which has been so useful but now I've got a weird bug I believe

I've got a react table with a subcomponent structured as such

```
<ReactTable
  data={Data}
  columns={columns}
  SubComponent={row => {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>I am the subcomponent</p>

        <button onClick={this.toggleHidden.bind(this)} >
          Click to additional information
        </button>
        {!this.state.isHidden && <p>Hello world</p>}
      </div>
    );
  }}
/>
```

And here's what that looks like in the browser - the blue button on the left opens and closes the subcomponent and that works just fine, I've used subcomponents like this throughout my React App with no problems

[image]

When clicking the 'Click to additional information' button I want to show additional information ('Hello world' in this example) it runs this piece of code

```
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      isHidden: true
    }
  }
  toggleHidden () {
    this.setState({
      isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
    })
  }
```

But what happens in the browser is that the subcomponent toggle is closed and looks like this

[image]

If I reopen the subcomponent you can see that the 'hello world' is now showing so if did work as I wanted but just automatically closing the subcomponent which I didn't want to happen

[image]

In the console I'm not getting any errors or logs from react-table - it seems that any time I try to set a state inside of the react-table subcomponent that it will automatically close like this

My guess is that setting the state has reset all the states and that is what is confusing react-table, but I don't see how it would be?

I've just updated react-table to the latest version 6.8.6 but still have the same problem

Is this a bug or is there something I've done wrong here?

Comment: Your code works fine using the official [subcomponent codepen example](https://codesandbox.io/s/r7483p449p)

Comment: Dyo - Well would you look at that ... so it does! OK! Well something with my local set up then, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 4):

i fixed this by collapseOnDataChange: false

Comment: Strangely this didn't work for me in version 6.8.6. The ReactTable has the manual prop, removing it didn't work either. It keeps unmounting and re-mounting the SubComponent when subcomponent prop changes...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I have a subcomponent and inside the subcomponent are buttons which trigger functions when clicked:

The delete button had the following code:

```
<button id="delete" onClick={this.deleteClient('id')}>Delete</button>
```

where deleteClient is defined as:

```
deleteClient = (clientRef) => {
      console.log(`deleting ${clientRef}`)

    }
```

With the above code, "deleting id" would console.log both when I opened the subcomponent and when I clicked on the button.

I resolved the problem by using a callback in onClick as such:

```
<button id="delete" onClick={() => this.deleteClient('id')}>Delete</button>
```

Now "deleting id" only console.logs once, at the appropriate time, which is when I hit "Delete".

**TL;DR:**

set your onClick to a callback function.

Hope that helps!